# Display CSS boxes side by side

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

css code

```
 #folder {  
width: 105px;
background: #BABABA;
position: relative;
 -moz-border-radius:    10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

This is CSS code to create boxes

php code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fold.css" /></style>
<?php 
function listFolderFiles($dir,$exclude){ 
 $ffs = scandir($dir); 
echo '<ul class="ulli">'; 
foreach($ffs as $ff){ 
    if(is_array($exclude) and !in_array($ff,$exclude)){ 
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){ 
        if(!is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)){ 

        } else { 
        echo '<div class=wrap><div id=folder><li>'.$ff.'</div></div>';    
        } 
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff,$exclude); 
        echo '</li>'; 
        } 
    } 
} 
echo '</ul>'; 
} 

listFolderFiles('.',array('index.php','edit_page.php')); 
?>
```

It Displays the boxes one below the other 
How to display the boxes side by side

Comment: show html  generated using this code...

Comment: considering that you are opening a li, showing the name of a directory and after that closing two divs I am guessing that your html is not valid (it isn't hierarchical)

Comment: try to use `display:inline` in your css..

Answer (score 1):

For side by side div element you need to add

```
float:left
```

in your css class will do work for you.

Check example : [DIV TABLE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47934/DIV-TABLE)

Comment: your tags are broken - opening and not closing correclty, it won't work cross browser

Comment: @PrasadSaitwal - welcome, dont forget to upvote and mark it as accpeted it it works perfectly for you

Answer (score 0):

```
float: left;
```

This will display boxes side by side, but you need to add following property to the item that comes after your boxes to correctly display.

```
clear: both;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#folder {display: inline-block;}
```

or  `#folder {float: left}`

Answer (score 0):

I'd say instead of doing:

```
echo '<div class=wrap><div id=folder><li>'.$ff.'</div></div>';
```

try:

```
echo '<li><div class=wrap><div id=folder>'.$ff.'</div></div></li>';
```

Making sure your `< li >` tag is closing correctly and wrapping your `divs` (or contrary, not sure what you're trying)

But your code doesn't seem really clean anyways, for example use class `.folder` instead of id `#folder` since ids should be unique by definition.

But i guess you gotta start somewhere, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

divs are block elements by default.

these elements consume all available width.

Even if you set a width to them, the margin will get the rest.

You can change this behavior by any of these methods:

- setting the display property from display: block to display:inline or
  display:inline-block
- floating the element with float:left or float:right
- position the div manually with position: absolute