# Display a CSS Grid and another element side by side, not below

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid, display

I’m using a CSS grid to [display two elements on top of each others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780614/css-how-to-position-two-elements-on-top-of-each-other-without-specifying-a-hei). It works great but now I want to put a third element side by side in line with the CSS grid.

SCSS:

```scss
.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  div {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="my-grid">
    <div> First element </div>
    <div> Second element </div>
</div>
<span> Third element </span>
```

I know I could simply put the third element in the grid element `div.my-grid` but I wanted another solution. Also, I tried to set display `inline` to the First and Second elements.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973058/display-css-boxes-side-by-side) but I think my question is more "useful".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `inline-grid` instead of `grid` to achieve what you want. This way, it won't expand in the whole row width and will make some space for other elements.

Example:

```css
.my-grid {
  display: inline-grid;
}

div {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
  <div> First element </div>
  <div> Second element </div>
</div>
<span> Third element </span>
```

**NOTE:** Read more about the [`grid` and `inline-grid` differences](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/premium-intermediate-css-css-grid/modules/premium-learn-css-grid/cheatsheet).

> The difference between the values inline-grid and grid is that the inline-grid will make the element inline while grid will make it a block-level element.